# Hints to improve speed performance for a search:search results retrieval?

Tags: performance, search, resultset, marklogic

I'm using `search:search` to retrieve a fairly large set of data (0.5K up to 3K) to plot some charts and also using the facet goodies from the search API to allow the end-user to facet-filter the data set, dynamically rebuilding the charts then. Retrieving from the DB and fetching the data to the client web-app takes its toll, around 5-10 seconds (less when data set is smaller), which is not very pleasant for the end-user. I know it's a conceptual issue, a thin balance/compromise between allowing the user to easily shape the data being plotted and the speed of this process, but, please any help/hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

P.S.: My attempts to use `search:parse` and then pass the query to `cts:query` raised an error like this: `[1.0-ml] XDMP-NONMIXEDCOMPLEXCONT: fn:data(<cts:and-query qtextjoin="AND" strength="20" qtextgroup="( )" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"><cts:element-range-query qtextpre="Jaar:" qtextref="cts:annotati...</cts:and-query>) -- Node has complex type with non-mixed complex content`

The options:

```
<search:options xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <search:search-option>filtered</search:search-option>
  <search:page-length>3050</search:page-length>
  <search:term apply="term">
    <search:empty apply="all-results"/>
    <search:term-option>punctuation-insensitive</search:term-option>
    <search:term-option>unstemmed</search:term-option>
  </search:term>
  <search:grammar>
    <search:quotation>"</search:quotation>
    <search:implicit>
      <cts:and-query strength="20" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"/>
    </search:implicit>
    <search:starter strength="30" apply="grouping" delimiter=")">(</search:starter>
    <search:starter strength="40" apply="prefix" element="cts:not-query">-</search:starter>
    <search:joiner strength="10" apply="infix" element="cts:or-query" tokenize="word">OR</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="20" apply="infix" element="cts:and-query" tokenize="word">AND</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="30" apply="infix" element="cts:near-query" tokenize="word">NEAR</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="30" apply="near2" consume="2" element="cts:near-query">NEAR/</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint">:</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LT" tokenize="word">LT</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LE" tokenize="word">LE</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="GT" tokenize="word">GT</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="GE" tokenize="word">GE</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="NE" tokenize="word">NE</search:joiner>
  </search:grammar>
  <search:additional-query>
    <cts:not-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
      <cts:or-query>
    <cts:collection-query>
      <cts:uri>All_Intakes</cts:uri>
      <cts:uri>Reports</cts:uri>
    </cts:collection-query>
    <cts:element-query>
      <cts:element xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">sem:triples</cts:element>
      <cts:or-query/>
    </cts:element-query>
      </cts:or-query>
    </cts:not-query>
  </search:additional-query>
  <search:debug>false</search:debug>
  <search:extract-metadata>
    <search:qname elem-name="USER_EI"/>
    <search:qname elem-name="Customer"/>
    <search:qname elem-name="TOTALAMOUNTTENANTEI"/>
    <search:qname elem-name="TOTALAMOUNTTENANTEI2"/>
    <search:constraint-value ref="Medewerker"/>
    <search:constraint-value ref="Klant"/>
    <search:constraint-value ref="TOTALAMOUNTTENANTEI"/>
    <search:constraint-value ref="TOTALAMOUNTTENANTEI2"/>
  </search:extract-metadata>

  <search:transform-results apply="snippet"/>
    <search:constraint name="Klant">
    <search:range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <search:element name="Customer"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
  <search:constraint name="Medewerker">
    <search:range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <search:element name="USER_EI"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
  <search:constraint name="Jaar">
    <search:range type="xs:int">
      <search:element name="Operation_Year"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
  <search:constraint name="Kwartaal">
    <search:range type="xs:int">
      <search:element name="Operation_Quarter"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>

  <search:return-metrics>true</search:return-metrics>
  <search:return-qtext>true</search:return-qtext>
  <search:return-query>false</search:return-query>
  <search:return-results>true</search:return-results>
  <search:return-similar>false</search:return-similar>
  <search:sort-order direction="descending">
    <search:score/>
    <search:annotation>Relevancy (Desc)</search:annotation>
  </search:sort-order>
</search:options>;
```

Comment: Hi Lenti... could you post the Search API options that you used? Also, what version of MarkLogic are you using?

Comment: On my dev machine I'm using ML 7 and on the public test server I've upgraded to ML 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention wanting to plot charts and create facets. Both would be based on values rather than full documents. It sounds to me like you could return, say, 10 document values but get larger lists from your facets. It looks like you're currently getting the values from extract-metadata. That's a good way to get some information to display about individual search results, but not a good way to get summary information about your data set.

Your constraints all use range indexes, which is good -- those will be resolved quickly. For your charts, you may want to use /v1/values to get co-occurrence values.

I'd change your page-length to 10 and add <facet-option>limit=100</facet-option> to the facets, then get your chart values from the facets instead of extract-metadata. Also, if you can arrange your indexes so that [unfiltered searches](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered) give accurate results, then your searches will run faster.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are trying to grab the complete search result in one page (start=1 page-length=99999999). You might want to change your strategy into getting results in smaller batches (page-length=100?), and simply iterating through the pages, and dynamically append more and more nodes to the chart. A good chart library should support that.

HTH!

Comment: Indeed my client asked for this strategy, getting all the data plotted at the beginning and then narrowing it down using the facet filters. I'll try and convince him the other way, to start with less data and only if needed once in a while to get a larger set of data to be plotted, accepting the limitations and performance tolls.

Comment: I don't necessarily mean delaying load of data, just mean doing it in batches. You can iterate the pages directly after each other. Loading all data point could take several seconds, maybe more, but the user experience would be much better; you would see data appear pretty much instantly, only a gradual increment..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll look into it, even if I would need to redo the in-memory aggregate calculations with every new page load.

Comment: What kind of aggregates? /v1/values allows pulling aggregates, and facets can be useful for counts as well.